# Node.js - every npm command gives an error

Tags: node.js, npm

```
C:\Users\Tim>npm
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:6:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I have Windows 10 64-Bit. I installed the latest version of node.js twice but the error remains the same.

Comment: Try npm install -g process-nextick-args

Comment: I'd trying reinstalling npm before installing process-nextick-args. Try installing Node.js with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which also installs npm.

Comment: npm install -g process-nextick-args gives me the same error

Comment: @JamesWright nvm does not support Windows. It's possible to update/reinstall npm by executing `npm install -g npm` though.

Comment: @leroydev True.

Comment: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows